# Amend previous return to move estimated payment?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, estimated-taxes, amended-tax-return

In a complicated situation for 2017 taxes (settled in 2018) ([Estimated State payment too big --> money back; + 2018 Tax Reform](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/107773/estimated-state-payment-too-big-money-back-2018-tax-reform)), it seems like I'd be better off had I made a State Tax estimated payment in 2017, instead of making it in  Apr 2018.

Is it possible to amend my 2017 tax return to "move back" that payment, even though I guess it would mean I'd owe interest on that amount from 31 Dec 2017 to Apr 2018?

Comment: wait, you want to take the 2017 tax deduction for the $20,000?  Legit but why??  You will only have to pay tax on it in 2018. Will you be in a lower bracket in 2018?

Comment: @Harper Per the linked question, there can be a benefit if the payment were made in 2017, due to the reduced deductibility of SALT payments starting in 2018.

Comment: I think your interpretation of the rule is what I hope it would be / what should be ( you estimate X in Apr 2018; do not claim deductions for it, then get it back (say exactly X in Oct 2018) --> nets to 0 income that year. But @nanoman's explanation, if I get it right, is that the money back is split in proportion "claimed deduction" / (claimed deduction (= my withheld) + 2018 estimate) for 2017, rest for 2018. I had 5X deduction in 2017, so most goes to 2017, so most is income in 2018 and I'm screwed. So might as well claim 20K more for 2017, since I get the same check back anyways, correct?

Comment: No, there's no proportioning, he's making it way more complicated than it is. If I loan you $20,000 and you pay it back, the principal is neither income nor expense and it's not reportable at all (the interest is).  This situation is like like you loaned the $20,000 to the state and the state gave it back to you.  Neither one is reportable.  The state *will* report the $20,000 as part of the amount on your 2017 1099-G for your tax refund... you just have to know to deduct it and not report it as income.

Comment: Hold on.  When you got your state tax refund, it should have included a 1099-G form reporting the state tax refund to the IRS.  **Was the $20,000 included in that figure?**

Comment: NYS doesn't mail that form; didn't know it existed. Found it online. Does include the 20K, like you said..

Comment: I think your analogy with a loan of 20K from Apr to Oct is pretty convincing. And if you've won against the auditor, I should definitely at least give it a try, reasoning is quite sensitive so I hope there wouldn't be too much penality / additional sanctioning if I lost...

Comment: @Harper Whoa, this discussion really belongs on the linked question if you are disagreeing with the accepted answer there. How do you explain "Recovery for 2 or more years" and Example 27 (HTML) or 28 (PDF) in Pub 525?

Comment: @ILoveCoding As I read it, what Harper won against the auditor is that when a refund is attributed as a recovery of taxes previously deducted, the full amount of the refund is not necessarily taxable, only the amount that led to an *incremental* deduction. It's another way of phrasing the "would have been" rule in my [answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/107774/64920) there. ...

Comment: @nanoman yikes.  I see your point. On your new comment I think you are right. But back to Pub 525, But you see the line before it, "recovery and expense in the same year"?  That's the nut right there for OP. The $20k payment and the state refund were in the same year, so they *cancel each other out*.   He reduces his 1099-G amount by the $20k, and includes a note why.

Comment: @ILoveCoding ... But this is not in dispute or the heart of your issue. The only person I have heard of contradicting this is that misguided auditor. (The IRS worksheets lead you directly through this so I can't imagine what the auditor was thinking.) It's entirely separate from whether you are allowed to allocate a refund entirely to 2018 payments when you made payments in both 2017 and 2018, or allowed to deduct in 2017 a payment made in 2018. All the evidence I have seen is *no*.

Comment: @nanoman well in my case, AMT was the issue.  What I did dodged AMT.  I can see why they flagged it, and I also think they'd flag OP if he tried the exact opposite, because it would confer tax advantage to him (lower brackets in 2018).  And indeed, all my payments were in the same calendar year.

Comment: @Harper For "recovery and expense in the same year", the key is that you can't just declare the corresponding expense to be *only* the 2018 payment. The "expense" corresponding to the recovery is the *entire* amount of 2017 state tax paid, and the recovery must be prorated to the payments. The explicit example in Pub 525 of 2017 state tax payments made in both 2017 and 2018, with a refund received in 2018, makes this clear.

Comment: OP, nanoman has a point.  I've lost confidence in my advice now.  We definitely agree amending your 2017 taxes to declare the payment made in 2018 is the wrong thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, amending a return allows you to correct misstated facts, or choose an alternate permitted tax treatment consistent with the facts, but not to calculate as if something happened in a way other than it did. There does not appear to be any provision allowing you to retroactively treat such a payment as being made in a different year.

Comment: except the $20,000 payment *was*  for his 2017 taxes.  if he actually owe the tax, there,d be no question that he could do as he plans.  he owed tax as ofDec 31 2017.  What followed was just pperwork.

Comment: @Harper The relevant fact for a federal deduction is when the payment was made, not when it could have been made.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely don't.  Nanoman told you one reason.  Here's another.

As far as IRS is concerned, OP would be creating "churn" unnecessarily.

By January 2018, it was well known that 2018 taxes would be changed.  **It was known most tax brackets would see their tax drop by 3%**.  So if someone could take a tax deduction in 2017, *and then pay income tax on that same amount in 2018*, they would be 3% richer -- or in OP's case, $600 richer on $20,000.  There aren't many opportunities to do that in the tax code, but by golly, State tax prepayment, deduction, refund, declaration is one of them.  I'm not saying OP planned this in 2018...

... but it *looks like* intentional  churning for that purpose. Especially now that the 2017 taxes are settled.

I stick by my earlier advice: Don't take the $20,000 as a deduction in 2017, and don't declare it as income in 2018 (i.e. exclude that amount from the "state tax refund paid" section on your 2018 1040). You did not benefit from the deduction, so there is no question you do not need to pay tax on the $20,000 of the refund.

How exactly you claim that appears to be complicated because your overall state payments were made in 2 years (man, I'll score a mental note never to do *that*.)  If you already have a tax accountant, let *him* figure it out.  IRS does not penalize you for mistakes made by your preparer.

Comment: Since the edits make the chronology harder to track, if as I gather you no longer stick by your earlier advice, perhaps edit your answer to make it readable for future users...

Comment: @ILoveCoding I already did that.    It definitely seems like tax life is easier if all your state payments occur in the same calendar year.  That's what I'd shoot for.